# How to add Basic Auth to Swift 2.2 Alamofire3 API request, for REST call to Drupal 7?

Tags: rest, basic-authentication

How can I add Basic Auth to this API request, in Swift 2.2 with Alamofire 3?

Here is my code:

```
    let voteEndpoint: String = "https://www.example.com/rest/votingapi/set_votes"
    let newVote = ["votes":["value":40, "uid":1, "entity_id":108]]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, voteEndpoint, parameters: newVote, encoding: .JSON)

        .response { request, response, data, error in
            print(request)
            print (response)
            print (error)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation try this.

```
let user = ""
let password = ""
let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]
Alamofire.request(.POST, voteEndpoint, parameters: newVote, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
```